# How to get a particular string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

i want to get a particular value from string in php. Following is the string

```
 $string = 'users://data01=[1,2]/data02=[2,3]/*';
 preg_replace('/(.*)\[(.*)\](.*)\[(.*)\](.*)/', '$2', $str);
```

i want to get value of data01. i mean [1,2].

How can i achieve this using `preg_replace`?

How can solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_replace is used to replace by regular expression!

I think you want to use `preg_match_all()` to get each data attribute from the string.

The regex you want is:

```
$string = 'users://data01=[1,2]/data02=[2,3]/*';
preg_match_all('#data[0-9]{2}=(\[[0-9,]+\])#',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => data01=[1,2]
            [1] => data02=[2,3]
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [1,2]
            [1] => [2,3]
        )

)
```

I have tested this as working.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` is the wrong tool, I have used `preg_match_all()` in case you need that other item later and trimmed down your regex to capture the part of the string you are looking for.

```
    $string = 'users://data01=[1,2]/data02=[2,3]/*';
    preg_match_all('/\[([0-9,]+)\]/',$string,$match);

    print_r($match);

/*
     print_r($match) output:

        Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => [1,2]
                [1] => [2,3]
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1,2
                [1] => 2,3
            )
        )
*/

    echo "Your match: " . $match[1][0];

    ?>
```

This enables you to have the captured characters or the matched pattern , so you can have `[1,2]` or just `1,2`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` is for replacing stuff. `preg_match` is for extracting stuff.

So you want:

```
preg_match('/(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*)/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

See what you get, and work from there.